# Are personality characteristics correlated with certain underlying features of the facial expressions of a person?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, personality

For instance is it possible to determine with some degree of accuracy if a person is ranks high in openness to new ideas by some photos of the person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These studies investigated the abilities of participants to guess peoples' personalities from photos of their faces.

Extraverts' faces were judged as more extraverted by participants.

> Ian S. Penton-Voak, Nicholas Pound, Anthony C. Little, and David I.
>   Perrett(2006). Personality Judgments from Natural and Composite Facial
>   Images: More Evidence For A “Kernel Of Truth” In Social Perception.
>   Social Cognition: Vol. 24, No. 5, pp. 607-640. 
>   https://doi.org/10.1521/soco.2006.24.5.607

Participants performed better than chance at judging conscientiousness and agreeableness from composite faces.

> Little, A. C. and Perrett, D. I. (2007), Using composite images to
>   assess accuracy in personality attribution to faces. British Journal
>   of Psychology, 98: 111-126. https://doi.org/10.1348/000712606X109648

Participants could identify agreeableness, neuroticism and physical health from the faces.

> Jones, A. L., Kramer, R. S. S., and Ward, R. (2012). Signals of
>   personality and health: the contributions of facial shape, skin
>   texture, and viewing angle. J. Exp. Psychol. Hum. Percept. Perform.
>   38, 1353–1361. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0027078

Comment: Can you please give a rundown of the correlations found in each of the papers?  This enables others to go directly to any paper determined by the correlation they are interested in

Answer (score 1):

Сorrelation Big Five and with facial features (static photo)
[image]

Hu, S., Xiong, J., Fu, P., Qiao, L., Tan, J., Jin, L., & Tang, K. (2017). Signatures of personality on dense 3D facial images. Scientific Reports, 7(1), 73. https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-017-00071-5

Penton-Voak, I. S., Pound, N., Little, A. C., & Perrett, D. I. (2006). Personality Judgments from Natural and Composite Facial Images: More Evidence For A “Kernel Of Truth” In Social Perception. Social Cognition, 24(5), 607–640. https://doi.org/10.1521/soco.2006.24.5.607